DNS issue on NGINX server pages won't load ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
OK so I have 5 pages:

login.html
otp.html
billing.html
index.html(for debugging purposes)
page-not-found.html


Intended logic

Enter into browser:

sub.domain.com/path (eg. sub.domain.com/login)

Served with:

https://sub.domain.com/path.html (eg. https://sub.domain.com/login.html)

This was all working and now for some reason that has stumped me - everything is returning ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - that is any combination I test ie. /login /login.html /
I have triple checked DNS records for domain (sub.domain.com) are all pointing to the webserver IP.
Note: Navigating to the server IP address loads the page!? DNS issue? I just ran ipconfig /flushdns - same thing.. flushing browser cache - same thing
The DNS records for the domain look like this (if relevant):
DNS record table from domain host6
NGINX (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.conf) file
server {
server_name sub.domain.com;
root /var/www/html/sub-domain;
index login.html;      # added just to see if it would load - it didn't 
                       # was previously /login.html
                       # changed for testing
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html page-not-found; #was previously /page-not-found - changed for testing
}

location /page-not-found {
    try_files $uri.html =404;
}

error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
location = /custom_404.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx.html;
    internal;
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
   if ($host = sub.domain.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name sub.domain.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED means problem with DNS and has nothing to do with nginx.

Thanks - ok my mistake, I stand corrected.
Any hint as to how I may debug this DNS issue? or what may possibly cause such a fault?

DNS is somehow not configured correctly. You odn't tell us the domain, so we can't check.

@vidarlo I would like to keep that private if possible - however I have provided the layout of the DNS table at the domain host.

Is there anything in particular you suggest I might look into  regarding the DNS?

A publicly available domain that is hidden may be just a personal homepage or irrelevant to business, which may leads to off-topic issues.

@djdomi sorry I should clarify - I would like to keep it private in this forum (ie not share the specific domain details) however the websites in question should be public ally accessible.

In other words, for the purspose of this exercise, I would prefer to refer to my domain by alias

Then we can't help you.

check with ping sub.domain.com

As the key point was changed, you should consider using classic DNS tools like dig, nslookup, and similar options to verify that the subdomain in question is reachable and exists.

@vidarlo the scope of this issue has broadened and I have posted a new question and included some domain names - please see my new post.
